# Tim5 initialization unable to trigger callback function on stm32

Tags: stm32, embedded, software, stmcubeide

I've been having a lot of trouble lately trying to get ADC3 to run on my STM32F746g-discovery board, so I started from scratch in order to try to pinpoint a problem. Unfortunately, now timer5 isn't even triggering the callback function associated with it!

Can someone help me out and tell what I'm missing? I'm just using the standard HAL libraries that were set up with STMCubeIDE so I assume it's a simple initialization problem in my main file.

````
#include "main.h"


ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc3;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim5;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM5_Init(void);

uint32_t adcValues[4];

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC3_Init();
  MX_TIM5_Init();
 
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim5);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim5);

  //HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc3, adcValues, 4);

  while (1)
  {
     
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 200;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC3_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC3_Init 1 */

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc3.Instance = ADC3;
  hadc3.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc3.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc3.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc3.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T5_TRGO;
  hadc3.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc3.Init.NbrOfConversion = 4;
  hadc3.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_2;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_3;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_4;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM5 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM5_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 1 */
  htim5.Instance = TIM5;
  htim5.Init.Prescaler = 5000;
  htim5.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim5.Init.Period = 1000;
  htim5.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim5.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim5, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim5, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 2 */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM5_IRQn, 1, 0); // Set priority
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM5_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOI_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PI1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOI, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */

/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc){
    UNUSED(hadc);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_1);
}

void HAL_ADC_ErrorCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc)
{
    UNUSED(hadc);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_1);
    // Error handling here. Toggle a different pin or use some other indicator.
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(htim->Instance == TIM5)  // check if the interrupt comes from TIM5
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOI, GPIO_PIN_1);
    }
}

void TIM5_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim5);
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out the `HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim5);` line in the main function will likely solve the problem.

Besides activating the interrupt, The `HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim5);` also starts the counter. So there is no need to start the counter in separate command. I guess the timer status register from first function call stays in busy mode so the second function returns with error.

These kind of abstractions are one of the problems of HAL. It would be better if activating the interrupt and counter were done separately.